# Error: "UnsatisfedLinkError: com.aparapi.internal.jni.OPENCLJNI.getPlatforms()" JNI configuration

Tags: java, macos, gpu, opencl, aparapi

I would try to execute an example script based on Aparapi, on MAC OS. I'm using the last version of Eclipse, but when I execute `DeviceInfo` example to get all the available devices:

```
public class DeviceInfo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KernelPreferences preferences = KernelManager.instance().getDefaultPreferences();
        System.out.println("-- Devices in preferred order --");
        for (Device device : preferences.getPreferredDevices(null)) {
            System.out.println(device);
        }
    }
}
```

it generates the

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.amd.aparapi.OpenCLJNI.getPlatforms()Ljava/util/List"
```

Is there someone who can help me?

Comment: I do not know Aparapi but I guess your LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not correct. It could be specified per Java System Property like `-Djava.library.path=...`

Comment: It looks for a library with machine code which is unavailable. Did you investigate what the exception means?

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56060097/ecplise-java-jni-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-loading-dll/5607231) will be of help?

Comment: I've already read different answers, and next, I add the flag "-Djava.library.path=\path\lib\.." but it doesn't work. @Michal Do you have any suggestions or examples?

Comment: @Abra it is similar problem, and I've already copied all resources file. However, It doesn't work.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I think it's a problem with JNI or libraries because I tried the same code on Windows and it only works by adding the Aparapi dependency to the pom file.

Comment: @Stefano: Did you try setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: @Michal How should I set this path?

Comment: @Stefano: it looks like the variable is called DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on OSX. At best set it via launchctl, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite Or make a symbolic link of it into /usr/local/lib , see https://github.com/nteract/nteract/issues/1523  It looks like it is quite messy on OSX (

Comment: @MichalI Unfortunately, I don't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite macOS Mojave 10.14.4 don't support directly OpenCL, I've executed Aparapi Framework.

I founded that the problem is the Aparapi Library. In particular, to resolve generated error I followed these steps:

- Download this repository https://github.com/aparapi/aparapi for AMD Graphic Cards
- Open the directory "**com.amd.aparapi**" and from terminal execute

  ```
  ant -f build.xml
  ```

  This command generates .jar file of this library
- Add the generate jar to the project's classpath in Eclipse
- Add the specific Aparapi library for your OS in:

  ```
  <your-workspace-path>/<your-project>/src/main/resources/osx/
  ```
- Before to execute the code, add the VM argument in "**Run Configuration**"

  ```
  -Djava.library.path=<your-workspace-path>/<your-project>/src/main/resources/osx/
  ```
- Execute your script!

Answer (score 0):

build the native assembly for Mac (`x86_64`) and add it into `jniLibs`; here's the [source code](https://github.com/aparapi/aparapi/tree/master/com.amd.aparapi.jni).

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` generally means, that it cannot find the native assembly.

Comment: How to build the native assembly for Mac?